# HashSet contains not working for Set of Long in Java only for some specific values?

Tags: java, hashmap, set, contains, hashset

I am trying to execute the below code :

```
for (Map.Entry<Long, List<FieldBO>> sectionField : sectionFieldMap.entrySet()) {
  if (secIds.contains(Long.valueOf(sectionField.getKey()))) {
//////
```

Here secIds is a Set which I am getting from the database. But here contains is only working for a few Ids. 
SecIds contains values [64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63]. Contains is giving true for 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59 but for other values even if I am checking with same like 64,65 etc which is present in secIds I am getting false. Please help me find why this is happening ?

NB: Please do not mark this as a duplicate there is no question/answer for this specific issue.

Comment: Are you sure that you need `Long.valueOf(sectionField.getKey())`, because `sectionField.getKey()` already returns Long? Nevertheless, are you sure that you don't modify secIds set?

Comment: We don’t know anything about your Set, so we can’t reproduce your problem.  Please edit your question and include a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.  (Note:  If you’re trying to access only the Map values corresponding to keys which are in `secIds`, you’d be better off calling the `retainAll` method of the Map’s keySet.)